# Swap elements in array if the next is bigger then current

Tags: arrays, ruby

I want change order in arr if the next element is bigger than current. 
Hot to modify the code, so it will be work?

```
arr = [5, 22, 29, 39, 19, 51, 78, 96, 84]
i = 0
while (i < arr.size-1)
    if arr[i].to_i < arr[i+1].to_i
        arr[i]
    elsif arr[i].to_i > arr[i + 1].to_i
            arr[i+1], arr[i] = arr[i], arr[i+1]
    end
    puts arr[i]
    i += 1

end
```

Returns: [5, 22, 29, 39, 19, 51, 78, 96, 84]
Instead: [5, 19, 22, 29, 39, 51, 78, 84, 96]

Comment: So what you want is essentially the same as `arr.sort`?

Comment: Why not just use `sort`?

Comment: Hi guys, this is an exercise in book. I must modify the code, normally I would use sort :D

Comment: `arr #=> [5, 22, 29, 19, 39, 51, 78, 84, 96]`. Which book are you using?

Comment: CS Programming in Ruby @sagarpandya82

Comment: So you want a bubble sort?

Comment: @EricDuminil Yep, i'm new i algorithms so it's kind difficult for me.

Comment: You now know the name of the sorting algorithm and you know the desired language. There are probably hundreds of corresponding articles on the Internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any of sorting algorithms depending on the size of array (n),

```
For Bubble Sort, Time Complexity is O(n^2)
For Merge Sort, Time Complexity is O(nlogn)
For Counting Sort, Time Complexity is O(n) but number in array must be 0.upto 10^6
```

**Bubble Sort:** It runs pairwise in one iteration and put the maximum element in last, In second iteration, put the second maximum element in second last position and so on till array is sorted.

1. Iterate (n-1) times [to find (n-1) max numbers]
2. Iterate (n-idx-1) times to swap pair of numbers if (first number is
   greater than next number)
3. If swapping stopped in inner loop means that array becomes sorted,
   so break the outer loop

Ruby Code:

```
def bubble_sort(arr)
      n = arr.size
      (n-1).times do |idx|
        swapped = false
        (n-idx-1).times do |i|
          if arr[i] > arr[i+1]
            arr[i], arr[i+1] = arr[i+1], arr[i]
            swapped = true
          end
        end
        break unless swapped
      end
      arr
 end

p bubble_sort([5, 22, 29, 39, 19, 51, 78, 96, 84])
```

**Merge Sort:** It runs on `divide and conquer` strategy, i.e if you know two halves of array is sorted then you can sort whole array by using `two pointer` strategy in O(n).

For Instance,

```
#first half : [4,5,7,9]
#second half : [1,2,10,15]

1. Take two pointer l and r assigned to starting index of both halves i.e 0
2. Iterate over l and r upto their lengths to consume both arrays
    if element at first_half[l] < second_half[r]
        Put first_half[l] in result_array 
        Increment l pointer
    else 
        Put second_half[r] in result_array 
        Increment r pointer
```

This merge operation will take O(n) to sort whole array.

Now, if we divide whole array into two halves recursively, we will get binary tree of height log(n) and each level will take O(n) to sort the subproblems (halves), resulting in O(nlogn) Time Complexity.

```
Base case would be : single element array is always sorted
```

Ruby Code:

```
def merge(left_sorted, right_sorted)
  res = []
  left_size, right_size = left_sorted.size, right_sorted.size
  l = r = 0
  loop do
    break if r == right_size and l == left_size # break if both halves processed
    if r == right_size or (l < left_size and left_sorted[l] < right_sorted[r])
      res << left_sorted[l]; l += 1
    else
      res << right_sorted[r]; r += 1
    end
  end
  res
end

def merge_sort(arr)
  size = arr.size
  return arr if size <= 1 # base case
  mid = arr.size/2 - 1
  left_half, right_half = arr[0..mid], arr[mid+1..-1]
  left_sorted = merge_sort(left_half)
  right_sorted = merge_sort(right_half)
  return merge(left_sorted, right_sorted)
end

p merge_sort([5, 22, 29, 39, 19, 51, 78, 96, 84])
```

**Counting Sort:** It works in O(n) by counting numbers appearance in array if numbers in array lies in range(0..10^6)

1. Keep count of each number of array in count_array.
2. Iterate from min_element to max_element of array, and put element in
   sorted_array if appeared i.e its count > 0

Ruby Code:

```
def counting_sort(arr)
  min, max = arr.min, arr.max
  count_arr = [0] * (max - min + 1) # initialize count_array with all 0s
  arr.each do |num|
    count_arr[num - min] += 1
  end

  res = []
  size = count_arr.size
  size.times do |i|
    count_arr[i].times do
      res << i + min
    end
  end

  res
end

p counting_sort([5, 22, 29, 39, 19, 51, 78, 96, 84])
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. It helped me a lot :)

Comment: Happy to help, If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

Notice that as you sort you are rearranging the array. Don't modify it, use it as a reference and place the sorted items in a new array.

Answer (score -3):

If you want to study algotirthms use C or C++.

```
def bubble_sort(array)
  sorted = array.dup
  i      = 0
  l      = sorted.length

  while i < (l - 1)
    j = 0
    while j < l - i - 1
      if sorted[j] > sorted[j + 1]
        tmp           = sorted[j]
        sorted[j]     = sorted[j + 1]
        sorted[j + 1] = tmp
      end
      j += 1
    end
    i += 1
  end

  sorted
end

puts bubble_sort([5, 22, 29, 39, 19, 51, 78, 96, 84])
```